# Прогресс бар на количество отданных байт определенному пользователю?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, nginx

Возможно ли сделать прогресс бар на количество отданных байт при нажатии пользователем на onclick (скачать файл). Прогресс бар показывает, сколько процентов отдано пользователю. В качестве 100% выступает filesize($filename)?

Comment: Это лучше сделать на JavaScript (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589917/show-a-progress-bar-for-downloading-files-using-xhr2-ajax)